# Scoreboard ASCII data - read

Tags: tcp, ascii

as a total noob I would like to understand what our venue scoreboard is sending us.

This is some of the captured data:
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G127\80 \80 \03-\01\7f\02G137\80 \80 \03,\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+\01\7f\02G16700 \03)
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G127\80 \80 \03-\01\7f\02G137\80 \80 \03,\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+\01\7f\02G16700 \03)
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G127\80 \80 \03-\01\7f\02G137\80 \80 \03,\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+\01\7f\02G16700 \03)
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G127\80 \80 \03-\01\7f\02G137\80 \80 \03,\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+\01\7f\02G16700 \03)
\01\7f\02G127\81200\80 \03>\01\7f\02G137\80 \80 \03,\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G127\81200\80 \03>\01\7f\02G137\80 \80 \03,\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+\01\7f\02G16700 \03)
\01\7f\02G127\81200\80 \03>\01\7f\02G137\80 \80 \03,\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G127\81200\80 \03>\01\7f\02G137\80 \80 \03,\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+\01\7f\02G16700 \03)
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G127\81200\80 \03>\01\7f\02G137\80 \80 \03,\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+\01\7f\02G16700 \03)
\01\7f\02G127\81200\80 \03>\01\7f\02G137\c0500\80 \03Y\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+
\01\7f\02G127\81200\80 \03>\01\7f\02G137\c0500\80 \03Y\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036
\01\7f\02G11\8271947 00 001\036\01\7f\02G127\81200\80 \03>\01\7f\02G137\c0500\80 \03Y\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+\01\7f\02G16700 \03)
\01\7f\02G127\81200\80200\03,\01\7f\02G137\c0500\80 \03Y\01\7f\02G147\80 \80 \03+
\01\7f\02G11\8071946 00 001\035\01\7f\02G11\8071946 00 001\035\01\7f\02G137\c0500\80 \03Y\01\7f\02G11\8071946 00 001\035
\01\7f\02G11\8071946 00 001\035\01\7f\02G127\81200\80200\03,\01\7f\02G11\8071946 00 001\035\01\7f\02G11\8071946 00 001\035

Can you please point me to the right direction how to use this captured data to resolve the time and score? How do you call this format of sent data? I just can not find the right clue to google for some tutorial, guides, info.

[image: Data chart content]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old-school fixed field message format.  And it isn't entirely printable ASCII or even ASCII as it contains bytes with values greater than 127 decimal.  So I'd call it a binary fixed field format.  The non-printable or non-ASCII bytes are "escaped" by a backslash followed by two hexidecimal digits, e.g., "\82" is 8*16+2 or 130 decimal.

Evidently you are interested in clock times and scores for hockey games, which is carried by message type 11.  It appears there a messages of other types included in your captured data including type 12, 13, 14, 15, and 17, which have different lengths.  You are going to need the documentation for all the other formats in order to decode this stream as it doesn't appear that message length is included in the message stream.

It also appears that there is a higher level protocol as the messages in the capture are preceded by "\01\7f\02G", which I wouldn't count on staying fixed as it must contain some relevant information, e.g. which match the message applies to.  You can better see the messages by highlighting this preamble:

[image]

It also appears that each message is followed by "\03" plus a single ASCII character that varies for no obvious reason.

The first message in the stream is type 11 and consists of the following 15 bytes: "11\8271947 00 001".  If you use the documentation for this message type you can decode it as follows:

- The first two bytes are "11" indicating it is message type 11.
- The status word in byte 3 is "\82" which has bits 7 and 1 set, indicating that the game clock is OFF.
- Byte 4 is "7" indicating it is an ice hockey game.
- Bytes 5-8 give the game clock as 19:47.  Note that when the game clock is less than one minute it is given in a different format, which includes tenths of seconds.
- Bytes 9-11 gives the home score of 0.
- Bytes 12-14 gives the guest score of 0.
- Byte 15 says the period is 1.

The last message 11 in the capture is "11\8071946 00 001".  The game clock is now ON and the value is 19:46.